# Java - Connection exception connection timed out

Tags: java, connection, windows-firewall

I'm doing a project using Java Sockets to communicate from nodes to other. Our simulation is configured this way, one machine instantiates multiple nodes of a distributed system and the other machine instantiates two clients trying to connect to the distributed system (which is basically a distributed DB).

The very strange behavior is the following: when one of my colleagues simulates the clients and my PC holds the nodes of the distributed system everything works fine. Clients connects and are able to send requests correctly.

But if we try to switch the roles (me simulating the 2 clients and him simulating the DDB) when my two client threads try to connect to his DDB the execution comes up with this error: ConnectionException connection timed out. Keep in mind that this behavior happens not only with one of my colleagues, but with both of them.

So I think it's more likely that the problem is on my side and i would like to solve it.

Can it be a firewall problem? This has happened both using my wifi or using the USB tethering of my phone (so maybe it's windows firewall at this point but I'm not good at it and I really don't want to mess up with something)

Edit: don't know if it can help but we're using a VPN with ZeroTier to simulate the local network

Comment: Could it be some security software that's installed on your computer?

Comment: @harrymc I only have windows defender rn.

Comment: You could disable temporarily the real-time scanning of Defender and the firewall, for testing.